# mysql c++ connector, how to keep the connection alive and reconnect if connection is broked?

Tags: c++, mysql, odbc, mysql-connector

i'm using [mysql c++ connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/). I want to connect to my database and keep connecting and reconnect if the connection goes away.

here is a code to connect:

```
driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
connection = driver->connect(Server, UserID, Password);
```

[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-connecting.html) it says that the method connection->isValid() and reconnect() are there to know whether the connection is alive and to reconnect if it is not. so i'm dong this:

```
bool MySqlCommunicator::Connect()
{
    try
    {
        bool connected = connection != NULL && (connection->isValid() || connection->reconnect());

        if (!connected)
        {
            connection = driver->connect(Server, UserID, Password);
            connected = connection->isValid();                
        }

        if (connected)
        {  
            statement = connection->createStatement();
            char str[255];
            sprintf(str, "USE %s", Database);
            statement->execute(str);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        delete connection;
        connection = NULL;
        return false;
    }    
}
```

then every time i want to execute a query i call Connect() to make sure the connection is ready. i assume the Connect() method will reconnect if the connection is not alive.

BUT the program crashes when reaching to this line:

```
            bool connected = connection != NULL && (connection->isValid() || connection->reconnect());
```

it cannot execute isValid() method, the program exits with message segmentation fault.

well, i changed the code to the following:

```
bool MySqlCommunicator::Connect()
{
    try
    {
        bool connected = connection != NULL; //connection != NULL && (connection->isValid() || connection->reconnect());

        if (!connected)
        {
            connection = driver->connect(Server, UserID, Password);
            //connected = connection->isValid();
            connected = true;
        }

        if (connected)
        {   
            statement = connection->createStatement();
            char str[255];
            sprintf(str, "USE %s", Database);
            statement->execute(str);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        delete connection;
        connection = NULL;
        return false;
    }    
}
```

now it works! if any error occurs it will reconnect to make it right. but this is NOT a solution! I want a proper solution for this.

- Why my first code is crashing on the mentioned line?
- Other methods like connection->setReadOnly() also make the program crash! what is the cause of it?
- What is the best way to make sure a connection is alive?
- What is the best practice to reconnect to a remote database in case of an error?

(Waiting for somebody to answer! thanks in advance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after hours of digging i found the solution. I cross-compiled the newer version of mysql c++ connector and used it to compile and run my code. now the methods isValid() and reconnect() are working. (the method setreadOnly() seems to be not implemented yet).

and my final working code is:

```
bool MySqlCommunicator::Connect()
{
    try
    {
        bool connected = connection != NULL && (connection->isValid() || connection->reconnect());

        if (!connected)
        {
            connection = driver->connect(Server, UserID, Password);
            connected = connection->isValid();
        }

        if (connected)
        {
            //connection->setReadOnly(false);

            statement = connection->createStatement();
            char str[255];
            sprintf(str, "USE %s", Database);
            statement->execute(str);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        delete connection;
        connection = NULL;
        return false;
    }

}
```